# unknown string on ASP .net page

Tags: asp.net

In one of my aspx page I have a option to connect to facebook , twitter .
When I load this page an unkown string like "adkadkskekkdkskdasf323dsk" is added before my html tag.

something like that

===========

```
abbfdabfdakadfkdafkdas
<html>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

===========

This unknown string is visible on browser. It's look very odd.

Some one have any idea why it is happening.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Someone may be modifying your code :)...

Answer (score 4):

Since it's outside of the HTML, you probably have a `Response.Write` outputting it somewhere in your code.  Do a search for "abbfdabfdakadfkdafkdas"  :).